# Google Sheet App Scripts : How to parse JSONs in Sheet A column A to Sheet B?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with Sheet A having [JSONs in column A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMgjY.png) and I'd like to populate Sheet B with the data with [respective rows and columns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qArBI.png1) However I'm not entirely sure how to start. I'm a bit confused about the whole process. First declaring sheet. I've seen people using the following:

```
function parseJSON()
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // Gets the Active Spreadsheet
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // Gets the first sheet
    var parsed = JSON.parse(json);

    sheet.appendRow([json.items[i].id, json.items[i].name, json.items[i].url]);
}
```

but I have in 1 active spreadsheet from sheet A to sheet B. So would i need to declare a second sheet (my sheet B)?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // Gets the Active Spreadsheet
var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[0]; // Gets the first sheet
var sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[1]; // Gets the first sheet

sheet2.appendRow([json.items[i].id, json.items[i].name, json.items[i].url]);
```

or i dont need those declarations and i just

```
function parseJSON(parsed)
{

    return [parsed.items[i].id, parsed.items[i].name, parsed.items[i].url]
}
```

so in Sheet B A1 i just put =parseJSON(SheetB!A) or something equivalent which im still unsure.

Also how do i declare what are headers and the values according to the JSON? Should the headers be declared?

```
const headers = ["dish_name","dish_price","dish_quantity"];
```

or is it possible to get the header from the JSON? How about the corresponding values? Does Apps Ssripts accept foreach loop?

**For additional context (for selected answer that helped)**

JSON Obj - `{"55":{"dish_name":"(Ala Carte) Claypot Soup with Rice and Char Kuih","dish_price":17,"dish_quantity":1,"dish_size_name":"default","dish_size_price":0,"dish_addon_name":"default","dish_addon_price":0,"dish_variation_name":"default","dish_variation_price":0}}`

the selected answer was able to split it up in key value pairs. so constant keys were headers, rows were the corresponding values.

Comment: Although I cannot use your sample values, I proposed a sample script as an answer by supposing your value. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your value and that was not useful, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample values as the text data? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- About your following script,

  ```
    function parseJSON()
    {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // Gets the Active Spreadsheet
        var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // Gets the first sheet
        var parsed = JSON.parse(json);

        sheet.appendRow([json.items[i].id, json.items[i].name, json.items[i].url]);
    }
  ```

  - In this case, `sheet`, `json` are not declared. By this, an error occurs.
  - When `sheet`, `json` are declared, `parsed` is not used.

#### Answer for question 1:

> but I have in 1 active spreadsheet from sheet A to sheet B. So would i need to declare a second sheet (my sheet B)?
> I think that it's yes. I think that when you want to retrieve the values from the column "A" of Sheet "A" and the values are put to Sheet "B", it is required to declare both sheets.

#### Answer for question 2:

> Also how do i declare what are headers and the values according to the JSON? Should the headers be declared? or is it possible to get the header from the JSON? How about the corresponding values? Does Apps Ssripts accept foreach loop?

I think that it's yes. When I saw your JSON data, it seems that several properties are existing. And, in your output situation, it is required to put the values in order. In this case, when the header value is used, the script can be easily prepared.

#### Sample script:

In order to achieve your goal, how about the following sample script?

```js
function myFunction() {
  // 1. Retrieve source and destination sheets.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));

  // 2. Retrieve values from source sheet.
  const values = srcSheet.getRange("A1:A" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 3. Create an array for putting to the destination sheet using the header value.
  const headers = ["dish_name","dish_price","dish_quantity"];
  const ar = [["", ...headers], ...values.flatMap(([a]) => Object.entries(JSON.parse(a)).map(([k, v]) => [k, ...headers.map(h => v[h] || "")]))];

  // 4. Put the array to the destination sheet.
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
}
```

- This sample script retrieves the values from column "A" of the source sheet "Sheet1" and converted the values to the 2-dimensional array and put the array to the destination sheet "Sheet2".
- Please modify the sheet names of the source "Sheet1" and destination "Sheet2" sheets for your actual situation, respectively.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much. It has split the json objects into rows and columns. If sheet 1 is Order_List which consists of Order ID, User ID, Order Menu(json objects), how to split according to order id? for exmple Order ID - 1, User ID - 558, Order Menu - `{"55":{"dish_name":"(Ala Carte) Claypot Soup with Rice and Char Kuih","dish_price":17,"dish_quantity":1,"dish_size_name":"default","dish_size_price":0,"dish_addon_name":"default","dish_addon_price":0,"dish_variation_name":"default","dish_variation_price":0}}`.

Comment: So that in sheet 2 maybe it'll be like:

Order ID | dish_id | dish_name |
       1            55       Ala Carte Claypot Soup 

but it should also be able to handle multiple dishes per order like:

Order ID | dish_id | dish_name |
       1            55       Ala Carte Claypot Soup 
                   255       Combo Meal Chicken Chop

Comment: @user2395639 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. But I would like to support you. So can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question.

Comment: okay. i think i will pose a new question instead of in comment here. it is difficult as it has limited characters. thank you for your help. please see my new question when you can. Oh but could you please explain what the ... in this `["", ...headers]` suppose to mean?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `["", ...headers]`, the spread syntax and the destructuring assignment. [Ref1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [Ref2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)